# DataGrid with a checkbox column to allow the user to select rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, groupstyle

Regards,

I have a `DataGrid` with a checkbox column to allow the user to select rows, a "select all" checkbox in the column header, and a "select all" checkbox in the group header.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True"  CanUserDeleteRows="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"     Margin="7,4,8,41" Name="customerDataGrid" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ColumnHeaderStyle="{Binding Source={StaticResource TabControlInnerBorder}}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid,  AncestorLevel=1}}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander>
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name}"   />
                                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" />
                                            <TextBlock  Text="Emp(s)" />
                                            <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Path=Name}" ClickMode="Press" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"  />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                   </Setter>
               </Style>
           </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
       </GroupStyle>
   </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

**.CS**

```
 private ICollectionView defaultView1;
 public main1_windows()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     List<Employ> empl = new List<Employ>();
     empl = LoadData();
     this.defaultView1 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(empl);
     this.defaultView1.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription  ("dep"));
     this.defaultView1.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Contains1);  
 }
```

---

```
public bool Contains1(object de)
{
    Employ order = de as Employ;
    //Return members whose Orders have not been filled 
    return (order.Name.ToString().Contains(textBox4.Text).Equals(true));
}
```

---

```
private List<Employ> LoadData()
{
    List<Employ> employ = new List<Employ>();
    employ.Add(new Employ()
        {
            ID = 2000,
            Name = "moh",
            DOB = new DateTime(1985, 5, 15),
            dep="pro",
            IsNew = false 
        });
    employ.Add(new Employ()
        {
            ID = 3000,
            Name = "jac",
            DOB = new DateTime(1985, 5, 15),
            dep="pro",
            IsNew = false 
        });
    employ.Add(new Employ()
        {
            ID = 4000,
            Name = "ahmad",
            DOB = new DateTime(1985, 5, 15),
            dep="admin",
             IsNew = false 
        });
    return employ;
}
public class Employ
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string dep { get; set; } 
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
}

private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.defaultView1.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Contains1);
}
```

---

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // I want when the apical true check box in the group all the rows in this group check box true value;
}
```

---

[image]

How I Can Select all rows in group
Thanks .

Comment: I need some c# code to select / deselect this  checkbox 
checkbox in group is selected ,All child this group selected >

Comment: How I Can Select all Checkboxes for the rows in a group? Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what object you have bound to your `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, but I'm going to assume that it is a collection. Providing that your data items in this collection have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (so that the UI will update), you can do this in your `Click`, or `ICommand` handler:

```
for (int index = 0; index < YourCollection.Count; index++)
{
    YourCollection[index].BoolPropertyBoundToCheckBox = true;
}
```

Comment: Dude, on this site, we prefer using words in comments. I think I get your point anyway. How about making a collection property, filling it with `LoadData()` and then updating it as in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This code correctly:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chc = sender as CheckBox;
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in mEmployees)
            {
                if (item.Dep.ToString() == chc.Content.ToString())
                {
                    item.IsSelected = true;
                    MessageBox.Show(chc.Content.ToString());

                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
 }
```